# Why aren't some unicode characters rendered in Google Chrome when using Proxima Nova?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, unicode, font-family

In Google Chrome, in Google Docs, certain unicode characters are not rendering. This only appears to happen when Proxima Nova is used. This is our company's default font so I can't simply use another font.

Throughout documents &#8203 characters are inserted in the document by Google Docs I assume, for some unknown reason. These are unicode "Zero width space" characters. These always appear as unknown characters in Proxima Nova, but if I change the font to Arial (for example), they render correctly as invisible characters. They render like the two square symbols either side of the word "must" in this screenshot:

[image]

Other characters such as the second level bullet point aren't rendered correctly either.

This seems to be an issue only with Google Chrome on Mac. Firefox and Safari render the characters correctly in the same Google Doc. This issue happens on almost all Google Docs I open that use Proxima Nova.

An inspect shows this as the code for the example I described above:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your copy of the Proxima Nova set might be missing the zero width space character.  I would first try obtaining a new and complete set of the font.

Comment: I have tried reinstalling the font file on my mac locally. But wouldn't the font be loaded in the web browser? It's only by chance that I have Proxima Nova ina font file on my mac. I shouldn't need it to see the font on the web.